# how to find python-mosquitto version

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

How do I see what is the version of the python-mosquitto package used by my program?  How do I find an old version of python-mosquitto (version 0.15) and remove it?

I'm running on Raspberry Pi, raspian

Answer (score 2):

0.15 is the version supplied with the raspbian default repositories so I think you installed through the package manager rather than pip.

Assuming that is the case, you can remove it with `sudo apt-get remove python-mosquitto`. You can get up to date versions from the mosquitto repository, which you can add as follows:

```
# Add the gpg signing key for the repository
wget http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/mosquitto-repo.gpg.key
sudo apt-key add mosquitto-repo.gpg.key

# Add the repository url and details to list of sources
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo wget http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/mosquitto-wheezy.list
```

Then update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-mosquitto
```

This will also give you the updated packages for other mosquitto components.

You could also install using pip:  `pip install mosquitto`.

Current versions of mosquitto.py don't contain the version number, but this has been fixed for future versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pip`, use `pip freeze | grep 'python-mosquitto'` to get the package version, and `pip remove python-mosquitto` to remove it.